# Uniqueness Theorem query.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Is there any proof which would show that the uniqueness theorem does not imply complete uniqueness of a ODE solution?

Would it have any relation between the interval where uniqueness is assumed to exist and the maximal interval of existence?

Thanks :)

Comment: Did you mean as in [*Theorem 2.4.1 or somethings else?*](http://staff.washington.edu/leep5/307/2.4.pdf). Regards

Answer (score 1):

The usual example is something along the lines of $$ y' = 2 \sqrt y, \; \; y(0) = 0.  $$
Then two legitimate solutions for $x \geq 0$ are
$$ y = 0  $$
OR
$$  y = x^2.  $$